# How to delete in spring-data-jpa in case of bi-directional mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have `country.java` entity class with `values` and `sources` as the one to many associations. 
I have `sources` and `values` entity also which has the bi-directional mapping to `country` class with many to one.

Now I want to delete all the `sources` belonging to a particular `country` Id and all values for that `country` Id.

And after delete, I want to add a new set of `values` for both these fields.

If I just do

```
country.setcharValues(new ArrayList<>());
countryRepository.save(country);
```

It is deleting everything even the properties which I don't want to get deleted.

Country.Java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Country",cascade = { CascadeType.ALL},fetch = FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval = true)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Values> charvalues = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Country",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},fetch = FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval = true)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Property> charProperty = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "CharCountry",cascade = { CascadeType.ALL},fetch = FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval = true)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Source> charSource = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: you can delete using repository of Values, Property, Source by findByCountry(Country country);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all `values` and `sources` associated with `Country`, and then want to add new `Values` and `Sources` in same transaction, you can try something like below,

```
    final Country country = countryRepository.findById(countryId).get();

    country.getSources().clear();
    country.getValues().clear();
    countryRepository.saveAndFlush(country);

    // add new Values and Sources to country

    countryRepository.save(country);
```

As `orphanRemoval = true` is used, this should work.